# How do I color a cell depending on the value of the cell next to it for several rows

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet where I write down my activities during a day and rate that activity by a number, like this:

```
    |Rating |Activity|
----------------------
1pm |   5   | Coding |
2pm |   3   | Shower |
3pm |   7   | Games  |
```

Now I want the background of these celles to change depending on the rating. For the actual rating cell I have no problems.

But when I want to color the activity cell I only manage to do it for one row.

I have three rules with custom formulas like this:

```
Green: F2>=7
Red  : F2<4
Yello: 7>F2>=4
```

And that works for that cell.

My question is how I can make these rules apply to a range of cells. Instead of only applying this rule to G2, I want to apply it to G2:G20. But when I do that the custom formula will still say F2 while what I need is basically "F{CURRENT_ROW}".

What I figured I need is some way to get the row number of the current row instead of 2 so I tried:

```
Green: F&ROW(F2:F20)>=7
Red  : F&ROW(F2:F20)<4
Yello: 7>F&ROW(F2:F20)>=4
```

And some other variations with " around the F and $ instead of & (I have no actual idea what I'm doing or what these symbols do which I hate) but I haven't found anything that works.

Is there a way to do this? I would like to avoid adding specific rules for every row.

Answer (score 0):

Easier than I expected, just changed the formulas to:

```
Green: F2:F20>=7
Red  : F2:F20<4
Yello: 7>F2:F20>=4
```

Worked for what I was trying to explain at least. I feel like an idiot now ^^

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be a slightly easier way to the same result, though the main benefit would be if your list is 'endless' - ie more than just F2:F20.

1] Since you are covering practically every possibility with your three conditions you may be able to skip one of them. For example, have *all* `Yello` (achieved with standard formatting) and only apply CF formula rules for `Green` and `Red`. The CF rules will override 'standard' formatting.

2] Select the whole of Column F before adding the rules. Then you need only define the rules for F1, so a little less typing. Admittedly this would mean F1 is subject to CF, which may not suit (though is easily handled by: an extra rule, with priority, for just that one cell; by changing the *Apply to range* `F1` to `F2` just for whichever rule F1 triggers; or otherwise).

3] Your `Ratings` seem to be integers so `>=7` might be simplified to `>6` (and `>=4` to `>3`).

4] Since all conditions are entirely dependent on the 'value of the cell next to it' it might be better UX to format the trigger values at the same time. That is, if colouring `Activity` based on `Rating`, give `Rating` the colour while you are at it. For that just extend the `Apply to range` by one column.